# ttyS1/uart1 initialised but not accessible through /dev/ttyS1

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, embedded

I'm not sure at which level I am having a problem.

System is a LeopardBoard DM368 running TI's own SDK / LSP / BusyBox kernel, the core Linux kernel is 2.6.x so using serial_core.c driver model.

By default the system has one UART enabled, UART0, mounted as `/dev/ttyS0` which is also used/invoked via the bootargs `console=ttyS0,115200n8 earlyprintk`.

We want to enable UART1 as `/dev/ttyS1`, so have gone through the low-level board initialisation code which sets up the pinmux, clocks, etc.

On booting, the low-level init reports (via printk's I added in) that it's enabled the UART1, and the driver code reports happiness too:

```
[    0.547812] serial8250.0: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x1c20000 (irq = 40) is a 16550A
[    0.569849] serial8250.0: ttyS1 at MMIO 0x1d06000 (irq = 41) is a 16550A
```

However, the port does not appear in `/dev/` (as `/dev/ttyS1`), and there are discrepancies with its status (flow control bits) which I suspect may be causing it to hang / never transmit:

```
cat /proc/tty/driver/serial
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:16550A mmio:0x01C20000 irq:40 tx:97998 rx:0 CTS|DSR
1: uart:16550A mmio:0x01D06000 irq:41 tx:0 rx:0 DSR
```

If I try to configure or modify it from the command line I get an error:

```
>: stty -F /dev/ttyS1
stty: can't open '/dev/ttyS1': No such file or directory
```

Bizarrely, if I change the bootargs to `console=ttyS1,115200n8 earlyprintk` the port works perfectly, and ttyS0 is still initialised correctly and works too:

```
cat /proc/tty/driver/serial
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:16550A mmio:0x01C20000 irq:40 tx:0 rx:0 CTS|DSR
1: uart:16550A mmio:0x01D06000 irq:41 tx:11563 rx:0 RTS|DTR|DSR
```

Now, that would be fine, but our bootloader must use UART0 so it would be nice to keep all the console stuff on ttyS0 and have ttyS1 for our secondary comms.

I inserted a couple of printk's into serial_core.c and it seems like uart_open() is never being called for ttyS1, I'm assuming it's something in the Linux init/startup sequence that needs modifying?

**Edited**: because I had fooled myself by doing an `echo >/dev/ttyS1` which had created a *file* called `/dev/ttyS1`, which clouded matters somewhat. I'm now 99% sure `/dev/ttyS1` is *never* created.

Comment: Have you tried to `mknod` the `ttyS1` or the TI's SDK use some `devfs` `udev`?

Comment: I haven't `mknod`ed, no, but I'll look into it. How would I find out if the SDK uses udev or devfs?

Comment: Use `mount` to see how your `/dev` is mounted, it should mention `udev` or `devfs` if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mknod /dev/ttyS1 c 4 65`

(if `/dev` is read-only use any writable directory mounted without the option `nodev`)

If the node is created without errors you can check if your patch is working reading/writing to the node or with any terminal emulator.

The problem is that the node isn't created?

If you're using some auto-magic dynamic dev fs like `devfs` or `udev` probably there's some *registration* problem in the middle (but I think not as most of the code is the same to bring up the ttyS0 and I guess adding a serial port is like adding a configuration row in an array in some platform file).

If you aren't using dev fs like that probably you have a `MAKEDEV` file somewhere in your build tree where to manually add a line for your new device to be created statically.
I've seen also a system where the dev nodes were created by an init script.

Comment: You have hit the nail on the head, `mknod` does the trick! Thanks very much, you've saved me a world of pain.